# How to set different heights on columns with flex-direction: 'row'

Tags: css, react-native, android-layout, flexbox

I'm trying to set container with two columns with different heights.
I have my container which has `flex-direction: 'row'` and `flexWrap: 'wrap'`.
Now I want to display there elements (only two can fit into container width) with different heights. I know that this can't be done with just flexbox, because rows has to be the same height when wrapping. So my question is: can this be done in React Native when Flexbox is default display type?

Code:

- Container:

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import Reminder from './../components/reminders/Reminder';

const reminders = require('../../public/reminders.json');

const RemindersPage = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.reminders}>
      {reminders.map((reminder) => {
        return <Reminder key={reminder.id} reminder={reminder} />;
      })}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  reminders: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
});

export default RemindersPage;
```

- Element:

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, Image} from 'react-native';

const Reminder = ({reminder}) => {
  let source = require('./../../../public/forest.jpg');

  return (
    <View style={styles.reminder}>
      <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={source} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.reminders}>
        {reminder.alerts.map((alert) => {
          return (
            <View style={styles.alert} key={alert.time}>
              <Text style={styles.time}>{alert.time}</Text>
            </View>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  reminder: {
    minWidth: '48%',
    height: 'auto',
    backgroundColor: '#333',
    color: 'white',
    padding: 5,
    marginVertical: 4,
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'white',
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
  },
  imageContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'white',
    paddingBottom: 8,
  },
  image: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 150,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
  },
  alerts: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    marginTop: 5,
  },
  alert: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  time: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'white',
    textShadowColor: 'black',
    textShadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 0},
    textShadowRadius: 5,
  },
});

export default Reminder;
```

My goal is that the element with red frame goes up as the arrow is pointing.

[image]

It should looks like this:

[image]

I don't want to set flex-direction to 'column' beacause I want this page to be scrollable.

Comment: check out `flex-grow` but honestly css grids would be ideal

Comment: Basically, NO!..

Comment: Something changed in 2022 maybe?